# Strange notations for partial derivatives?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definition, partial-derivative

I’m reading this question:

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be concave, $\lambda_{0} \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$.
> a) Show that
> $$
> 0 \in \partial f\left(\lambda_{0}\right) \Rightarrow f\left(\lambda_{0}\right)=\max f
> $$
> b) Let $f$ also be differentiable. Show that
> $$
> \partial f\left(\lambda_{0}\right)=\left\{f^{\prime}\left(\lambda_{0}\right)\right\}
> $$

In $a)$, what does “$0 \in \partial f\left(\lambda_{0}\right)$” mean? Shouldn’t it be $\bf{0} = \partial f\left(\lambda_{0}\right)$?

In $b)$, aren’t those two the same thing by definition?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative

Comment: Also keep in mind that the function is not convex in your case, but concave (which is about the same thing, think about $-f$ begin convex)